# Loading screen userform

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried just about every option of modeless possible to get this to work I just cannot get it figured out. What I have is a Userform ( Main_Window ) that has a script, and on command button it executes Master_Flex_Filter_Generate()

In that code I have

```
    ' Connect and execute the SQL
    rs.Open sqlString, conn, adOpenStatic

' Check if we have data.
    If Not rs.EOF Then

        ' Dump column names in first row.
            For i = 0 To rs.Fields.count - 1
                ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i).Name

            Next i

        Do
            ' Transfer results beginning at A2 from rs
                ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

        Loop Until rs.EOF

        ' Close the recordset
            rs.Close

        ' Define Record_Count as the amount of records returned. Subtract 1 for the header
            Record_Count = Cells(Rows.count, "A").END(xlUp).Row - 1

        ' Return box on success
            Answer = MsgBox((Record_Count & " Records returned") & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Reminder" & vbCrLf & "- This data set is already defined as a range. This allows you to create a new pivot table and use the named range: " & ActiveSheet.Name & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to create a Pivot Table from this data?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Query generated succesfully")

        ' close user form
            Unload mod_loading
            Unload Main_Window

        ' Clean up
        If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
        Set rs = Nothing


        'Now lets define this data as a range for pivot table use
            Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
            Dim ActSheetName As String

            'This sets up an object reference to the activesheet
            Set ActSheet = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

            'This places a string value in the variable
            ActSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
            Set ws = ActiveSheet
            Set sheetname = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet



           ws.Range("A1").Select
           ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="data", RefersToR1C1:= _
               "=OFFSET(R1C1,0,0,COUNTA(C1),COUNTA(R1))"

           wb.Names("data").Name = ActSheetName

        'Filter, freeze pain, and align columns
            Rows("1:1").Select
            Selection.AutoFilter
            Selection.Font.Bold = True
            Columns("A:IV").AutoFit
            With ActiveWindow
                .SplitColumn = 0
                .SplitRow = 1
            End With
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True





        'Take answer form msgbox and do something with it
            If Answer = vbYes Then
                'If yes, create pivot table
        Sheets("Pivot").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
            "data", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
            :="Pivot!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:= _
            xlPivotTableVersion14
        Sheets("Pivot").Select
        Cells(1, 1).Select

            End If

    Else
        mod_loading.Hide
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned for your criteria.", vbCritical
    End If
```

This form works perfectly as is here. I have another Userform called mod_loading that looks like this

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
DoEvents
Do
    mod_loading.loading_beag.Visible = False
    mod_loading.loading_splines.Visible = True
        Sleep 2000
        DoEvents
        mod_loading.loading_splines.Visible = False
        mod_loading.loading_sheep.Visible = True
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
        mod_loading.loading_sheep.Visible = False
        mod_loading.loading_meteor.Visible = True
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
        mod_loading.loading_meteor.Visible = False
        mod_loading.loading_ozone.Visible = True
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
        mod_loading.loading_ozone.Visible = False
        mod_loading.loading_terrain.Visible = True
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
        mod_loading.loading_terrain.Visible = False
        mod_loading.loading_gravity.Visible = True
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
        mod_loading.loading_gravity.Visible = False
        mod_loading.loading_advisor.Visible = True
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
        mod_loading.loading_advisor.Visible = False
        mod_loading.loading_pool.Visible = True
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
        mod_loading.loading_pool.Visible = False
        mod_loading.loading_leaks.Visible = True
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
        mod_loading.loading_leaks.Visible = False
        mod_loading.loading_beag.Visible = True
        Sleep 5000
        DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

Both of these forms work as is, where I'm having the problem is placing mod_loading.Show anywhere in Master_Flex_Filter_Generate(). No matter what I set for modeless the mod_loading will run until it completely finishes. It won't let the code in Main_Window to continue running, so it halts that code. Any ideas? I was thinking it's perhaps because I'm not playing mod_loading.Show inside a loop, but since my connection string doesn't have a loop I can't figure out how to do it.

I placed the code inside If Not rs.EOF THEN but 99% of the code loads on rs.Open which is outside of the loop.

EDIT

Okay so I have changed my script all around and have placed all SQL logic inside the userform for the loading dialog. So I have Main_Window which is the form, then it calls the sub from the loading userform which pops up just fine. So I now have the loading dialog pop up and goes away just fine as intended. My only problem is now, it doesn't loop through my sleep commands. It just remains on the very first one.

Here is my code for the loading userform

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
```

DoEvents
Call Master_Flex_Filter_Generate

```
       DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_beag.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_splines.Visible = True
            Sleep 500
        DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_splines.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_sheep.Visible = True
            Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_sheep.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_meteor.Visible = True
            Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_meteor.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_ozone.Visible = True
            Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_ozone.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_terrain.Visible = True
            Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_terrain.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_gravity.Visible = True
            Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_gravity.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_advisor.Visible = True
            Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_advisor.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_pool.Visible = True
            Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_pool.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_leaks.Visible = True
            Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
            If Cancel = True Then
                Unload loading_masterflexfilter
                Exit Sub
            End If
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_leaks.Visible = False
            loading_masterflexfilter.loading_beag.Visible = True
            Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
```

End Sub

Comment: I can't replicate this.  In Excel 2010, `userForm.Show vbModal` runs `UserForm_Activate()` synchronously (note: control is returned to the calling code when the userForm is *closed*) and `userForm.Show vbModeless` runs it asynchronously.

Comment: @aucuparia the vbModeLess tag isn't changing anything for me.. the only way it works is to remove the loop and all time events from mod_loading. Then that window will display until the SQL query is done... but that is not desired.

Comment: Here's my test code: `Public Sub foo(modal As Integer)    //
    Debug.Print "Sub Start", Now()    //
    UserForm1.Show modal    //
    Debug.Print "Sub Finished", Now()    //
End Sub` then, in a blank UserForm1, `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()    //
    Debug.Print "Starting UserForm_Activate()", Now()    //
    Sleep 5000    //
    Debug.Print "Finished UserForm_Activate()", Now()    //
End Sub` (replace // with line breaks, and declare the `Sleep` function as well).

Comment: Results - modal: `thisworkbook.foo vbmodal      //
Sub Start     14/10/2015 08:36:10       //
Starting UserForm_Activate()              14/10/2015 08:36:10       //
Finished UserForm_Activate()              14/10/2015 08:36:15       //
Sub Finished  14/10/2015 08:36:20       //`
 For modeless - 
`thisworkbook.foo vbmodeless    //
Sub Start     14/10/2015 08:36:31      // 
Sub Finished  14/10/2015 08:36:31       //
Starting UserForm_Activate()              14/10/2015 08:36:31     //
Finished UserForm_Activate()              14/10/2015 08:36:36     //`

Comment: I'm still having difficulty with this.. the underlying form Main_Window is what is working and querying the database.. but when the loading screen opens it stops the code in Main_Window, and waits for the loading to finish through its sleep functions.

Comment: @aucuparia I have posted an update